# Resource cleanup in Erlang

Tags: erlang

In Erlang, is it possible to have a cleanup function automatically called when all references to a resource go away? For example, will the native file handle that is opened by calling `file:open/2` ever be closed if `file:close/1` is never called? If this is possible, how is it done? If not possible, are there Erlang idioms that make resources leaks like this not an issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `file` [documentation](http://erldocs.com/R14B04/kernel/file.html?i=18&search=file%3a#open/2):

> IoDevice is really the pid of the process which handles the file. This process is linked to the process which originally opened the file. If any process to which the IoDevice is linked terminates, the file will be closed and the process itself will be terminated. An IoDevice returned from this call can be used as an argument to the IO functions (see io(3)).

So, if the process that opened the file dies, the file will be closed automatically.

If you are using OTP and you want to be absolutely sure your file was closed when your process dies, add `file:close` to the `terminate` function. Of course your gen_* must be attached to a supervisor.

Comment: I think that I get it. So if you have code that manages a resource (like a file), you `link/1` your process to the callee's process. That way your code can handle the exit signal when the callee terminates and clean up. I take it that there's no support for a finalizer-like callback if the resource handle (i.e. IoDevice) were to be garbage collected even while the callee's process continues. And, if that's the case, using processes in a fine grained way is good practice for minimizing resource leaks (among other reasons).

Comment: If your process is long-living and you use the file only for a brief period, you must call the close function directly. If an error occurs and your process dies, the file will be closed automatically, no need for a explicit link.

Comment: @FrankHunleth: For finalizer-like callback see `after` clause in  [`try`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id78318) expression. It was added to language recently but it is not preferred way how to do it. Spawning processes and monitoring or linking is more convenient.